# ¿Cómo agregar URL en Javascript usando get_template_directory_uri?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, url

Tengo esto en  un archivo de Js

```
const base_url = "http://midominio.com/wp-content/themes/mitema/js/js_nuevo.js";
```

Y quiero reemplazarlo por algo como esto:

```
const base_url = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/js_nuevo.js";
```

Pero me da error en consola que no encuentra la ruta.

La verdad no se como hacer para que se renderice esa ruta automáticamente. Alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor?

Comment: Haz un `echo base_url` o un `var_dump(base_url);` y verifica qué muestra. Ten en cuenta que si usas un tema hijo deberás usar `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` en lugar de `get_template_directory_uri()`.

Comment: Y, para más claridad en el código, yo definiría la constante así: **`const base_url = sprintf( "%s/js/js_nuevo.js",get_template_directory_uri() );`**